# Batch Apex Governor Limit and Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, batch, governorlimits

If a certified managed package initiates batch apex, does it come under governor limits of native org for batch apex?

e.g. per documentation:

> The maximum number of asynchronous Apex method executions (batch Apex,
>   future methods, Queueable Apex, and scheduled Apex) per a 24-hour
>   period
>   = 250,000 or the number of user licenses in your organization multiplied by 200, whichever is greater

Does this include batch apex initiated by a managed package? Or does managed packages get a separate limit for batch apex?

I know from the documentation that managed package has separate number of DML and SOQL execution limit per transaction.

[Apex Limits](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm#certified_pkg_limits_section)

I was wondering what the behavior is for batch apex.

Answer (score 4):

As per the link in your question, the following are not separate limits for the managed package, rather they're counted towards the whole org:

- The total heap size
- The maximum CPU time
- The maximum transaction execution time

Having said that, your DMLs inside the batch will have a separate limit for the managed package namespace, though the maximum CPU time for an example will stay the same for all apex in your org, regardless whether the code is executed withing the namespace of the managed package or your org in general.

So in regards to method executions, [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm) says that the **maximum number of asynchronous Apex method executions** falls into the **Force.com Platform Apex Limits**

> "The limits in this table aren’t specific to an Apex transaction and
>   are enforced by the Force.com platform."

Meaning that the governor limit will apply for the managed package as well.