# How many records can an APEX batch is capable of processing

Tags: batch

I am trying to find the total number of records (volume) an APEX batch is capable of processing overall. Can someone please help me in this.

- Need to know the volume not limit

Question # [69265](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69265/batch-apex-governor-limit-and-managed-package) on SOF gives batch limits

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Providing the `start` method returns a `QueryLocator` (and not the `Iterator` alternative), a single [batchable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) can process [50 million records](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176644&language=en_US):

> A maximum of 50 million records can be returned in the
>   Database.QueryLocator object. If more than 50 million records are
>   returned, the batch job is immediately terminated and marked as
>   Failed.

Each call to the `execute` method must stay within the [other governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm), but that can usually be achieved by selecting a batch size that is small enough. So for example 20 million records could be processed using a batch size of 1,000 records so the `execute` method gets called 20,000 times.

Comment: Can you confirm that using an `Iterator` limits record count to 50,000 (i.e. standard SOQL record limit)?

Comment: @Mossi  Yes that is my understanding per the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) that say "If you use an iterable, the governor limit for the total number of records retrieved by SOQL queries is still enforced" [which is](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) 50,000.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is subject to the task or transaction at hand. The reason for using a batch:

> *when you have many operations for each record being passed in and are running into governor limits. By limiting the number of records, you are limiting the operations per transaction.*

**[Using Batch Apex (Documentation)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm)**

> A maximum of 50 million records can be returned in the Database.QueryLocator object. If more than 50 million records are returned, the batch job is immediately terminated and marked as Failed.

Keep in mind that if your batch iteration grabs too large a number of records than you may still run into governing limits

> *`Database.executeBatch` can have a maximum value of **2,000*** [...records per iteration in your batch]
>
> *With Apex Flex Queue, **you can submit up to 100 batch jobs without getting an error.***
>
> *The outcome of Database.executeBatch is as follows.
> The batch job is placed in the Apex flex queue, and its status is set to Holding.
> If the Apex flex queue has the maximum number of 100 jobs, Database.executeBatch throws a LimitException and doesn’t add the job to the queue.*